# setting topLeft and bottomRight for QRectF

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is that when I'm setting values to QPointF, I get strange values like 1.32841e+09 when I check what they really are.
I'm not getting those values when I print it out on the sixth line in the while-loop.

```
void MainView::showAllGraphs(){
     QMapIterator<QString, QRectF> i(graphRectangles);
     QPointF topLeft;
     QPointF bottomRight;
     QRectF maxRect;
while (i.hasNext()) {
     i.next();
     qreal tlX = i.value().topLeft().x();
     qreal tlY = i.value().topLeft().y();
     qreal brX = i.value().bottomRight().x();
     qreal brY = i.value().bottomRight().y();
     QTextStream(stdout) << tlY << " " << brY << endl;
     if(tlY < topLeft.y()){
         topLeft.setY(tlY);
         topLeft.setX(tlX);
     }
     if(brY > bottomRight.y()){
         bottomRight.setY(brY);
         bottomRight.setX(brX);
     }
}
maxRect.setTopLeft(topLeft);
maxRect.setBottomRight(bottomRight);
QTextStream(stdout) << topLeft.y() << " x " << topLeft.y() << endl;
graphicsScene>setSceneRect(maxRect);
graphicsView->fitInView(maxRect);
matrixUpdated(graphicsView->matrix());
}
```

With the first print, I get values between -100 and 100 (which is valid). When I print out at the end I suddenly get a value like 2.45841e+09 or sometimes 0. I don't want it to change to that.

So what is the reason for this change in value? I can't figure out why it is set to a value like that.

Comment: Your example is a bit inconsistent (why are you printing `topLeft.y()` twice, for instance?)  Further, it would be more instructive if you took out any extraneous calls that aren't central to your problem.  For instance: does the issue still exist if you take out the graphicsScene/graphicsView/matrixUpdated calls?  Can you isolate the issue in a small program which passes a fixed list of information in?  Take a look at http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topLeft` is not initialized.

You only assign a value to `topLeft`(or `bottomRight`) if your conditions are met. So make sure to initialize your rectangle to sensible values which allow meaningful comparisons in your if statements.

Furthermore, `topLeft` is not *changed* as you assume. In the while loop, you print the elements of the map (`tl` and `br`), **not** (the uninitialized) `topLeft` that you print after the while-loop. That's why you get different results.